Anime Movie About a Bizarre Pet Shop Owner
I am looking for the title of an Anime Movie (or Series??) about a police officer investigating about a Pet Shop and the incidents about the fate of the clients that each has bought a pet from this shop. The shop keeper also gives special instruction to clients that buys from him.
Some clients that I can recall are:

A man that bought a siren that looks like his girlfriend that eats him in a pool because she got hungry (the shop keeper instructs him not to let her get hungry).
A couple that lost their daughter that bought a girl that looks like their daughter that has ears of a bunny (the shopkeeper instructs them not to feed her too much but the couple seems to crossed this taboo at the end).

This films looks classic and somewhat sort of sensual and emotionally intricate. It was from around the year 2000.

When did you watch it?

About year 2000.

Sounds like the anime TV series Pet Shop of Horrors that ran for 4 episodes in 1999.

Episode 1 – Daughter. A rich couple has lost their only daughter, Alice. Fortunately, Count D is able to acquire a very rare species of rabbit that looks exactly like Alice. The couple is overjoyed and immediately takes the rabbit home. But their love for Alice makes them breach one of the contract's terms.
Episode 2 – Delicious. The popular idol singer Evangeline Blue and her manager Jason are about to be wed on a luxury ship when Evangeline "accidentally" falls overboard, her body never to be found. The heartbroken Jason travels to Count D's to pick up a pet that Eva had supposedly ordered. But to his surprise, the pet turns out to be a very large rare species of a fish but looks (to him at least) like a mermaid who looks exactly like Eva.

It was based on a horror manga. Here are some clips from the mermaid episode:




Oh! I think this Anime was the Pet Shop of Horrors.

Indeed. Seems we posted this simultaneously. Should I delete mine?
